# API doesn't support cors. How do I fetch?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fetch data from an API that DOES NOT support CORS.

```
fetch("https://app.pixelencounter.com/api/basic/monsters/random", {
    headers: {
        Content-Type": 'image/svg+xml;',
    }})
    .then(response => {
            return response.text()
    })
    .then((data) => {
            console.log("Data:", data);
    });
```

But keep getting the error cors is not supported. How would I disable fetching with cors? I actually don't want to get cors working, cause it's not supported by the server as mentioned [here](https://pixelencounter.com/Api)
I tried `mode: 'no-cors'` but like this I can't access the response cause it's type is `opaque`.

Comment: You proxy it though your server

Comment: So I actually can't fetch it from the frontend?

Comment: @TKsomewhat — You asked this 25 minutes ago. The duplicate told you to proxy it through you server and that you couldn't fetch it from the frontend (and why). Don't just delete questions and re-ask them.

Comment: @Quentin If i don't get a proper answer, just a question that's not exactly like mine, I do.

Comment: You got a proper answer. It explained everything in detail.

Comment: Well, instead you could've answered it on the question isntead of letting me search the other answers for just exactly what I need. But whatever. SO is not known for their friendly members.

Comment: The answer has big chunky headings to help you find the bits you care about… and it is already written. It's a FAQ. There would be a lot of duplicate content if all the duplicate questions were answered, explicitly, over and over.

Comment: And that would be a problem? Questions can't be deleted permanently anyways.